# How to import facebook comments to Wordpress database?

Tags: comments, import, facebook, disqus

I want to get rid of Facebook Comments from my website, but I have a lot of comments there. Is it possible to import facebook comments to normal Wordpress comments system or something else (i.e. disqus?) I just can't find anything.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use facebook's graph API to write a script that will import the comments from facebook into your site.  Then Disqus can import your comments from the site.

This is the [api instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/comments) for getting comments.  Alternatively, it looks like someone has already written a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-comments-importer/) that does this though they charge.